# Accessing sublevels of nodes via recursion

Tags: c#, recursion, visual-studio-2005, nodes

The code below (credits to Neill Verreynne for the idea) is for when multiple nodes (or rather child nodes) are selected, such nodes would have a corresponding code that would execute with a click of a button. So at the button click event, the RecurseTree method would fire and recurse an xml list until all of the checked nodes' codes has been executed. What I want to do now is to also access not only the parent node and the child node but also the child's child nodes. Is there any way to do this, what do I have to add to the code provided below.
Thanks!
I'm using VS 2005 C#. .NET 2.0. Winforms.

```
private void RecurseTree(TreeNode node,string ParentNode)

    if (node.Checked == true)
    {
        //code goes here
        sysvar=[ParentNode];
        sysvar1=[node.Name];
        //and something else
        //with the node's name, a file matching the name of the node would be executed on an external application
    }
    foreach (TreeNode childNode in node.Nodes) RecurseTree(childNode, ParentNode);
}

private void msrstart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (mMsr != null) mMsr.Start();
    foreach (TreeNode node in treeView1.Nodes) RecurseTree(node, node.Name);   
}
```

It works for the parent node and the child node, of course. But I came across a child node having another sublevel node and the code shown above apparently works only for the top level node and the child nodes. What I want to happen is when I select this node (the child's child node), the snippet inside the if statement would be applicable to it as well with only a bit of a difference, in which, sysvar1 would now be `sysvar1=[node.Name"::"childNode.Name]` which is the top and 2nd level of nodes. I'm trying to access the 3rd level, as well. Problem is I dunno which to manipulate in order to make this happen.

P.S. I don't exactly know how to phrase a particular question or statement that would fit my problem. And for that, I apologize.

Excerpt of the XML file if you want to know:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<systemvariables version="4">
    <namespace name="_08_Customer_Diagnostics" comment="">
      <namespace name="_08_10_FreezeFrameData" comment="">
        <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_08_10_01_FFD_Operation" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
        <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_08_10_02_Image_FFD" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
        <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_08_10_01_FFD_Operation_start" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
        <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_08_10_02_Image_FFD_start" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
      </namespace>
  <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_08_01_Diag_Customer_Service_0x10" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
  <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_08_06_Diag_Customer_Service_0x3B_start" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
  <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_08_05_Diag_Customer_Service_0x30" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
  <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_08_07_Diag_Customer_Service_0xA0" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
  <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_08_02_Diag_Customer_Service_0x12" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
  <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_08_03_Diag_Customer_Service_0x1A_start" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
  <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_08_08_Diag_Customer_Service_0xA8" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />
  <variable anlyzLocal="2" readOnly="false" valueSequence="false" unit="" name="_08_03_Diag_Customer_Service_0x1A" comment="" bitcount="32" isSigned="true" encoding="65001" type="int" startValue="0" minValue="0" minValuePhys="0" maxValue="4" maxValuePhys="4" />

</namespace>
</systemvariables>
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. There is already a full recursive tree walk. XML? Please make your example (much) smaller. What exactly is expected? What goes wrong?

Comment: I edited it, I'm not sure if it's clear now or anything.